# Can Etree handle these kinds of XPath Queries

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

Can Pythons XML Parsing library [Etree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) take complex XPath queries like the following?

```
# Note the "[text()=\"USER_4D\"]"
assert root.find("Group/EnvConfig/Overrides/Override/Key[text()=\"USER_4D\"]") != None
```

I am getting the error `SyntaxError: invalid predicate` on the above line. If I remove the 'predicate' `[text()=\"USER_4D\"]` then no expection/error is raised.

Whats causing this error? Is my XPath incorrectly formatted or can Etree not perform these kinds of XPath queries? Can you provide advice on how to fix this?

I hope I dont need to use a custom XML Parsing library because I am just trying to make some simple unit tests using Pythons in built XML Parsing libraries. Are there other native Python libraries than can handle this XPath query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElementTree does not support the kind of XPath expression used in the question. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support.

To assert the presence of a `Key` element with the text content `USER_4D`, you could use something like this:

```
Key = root.find("Group/EnvConfig/Overrides/Override/Key")
assert Key != None             # Element exists
assert Key.text == "USER_4D"   # Element has specific content
```